# How to know the functions included as a part of a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to the python. I am using this Seaborn module for instance and I wanted to know is there any way I could know what are all the functions included as part of this module (such as scatterplot, regularplot or any other things which could be used using this module).

I tried using pip list and it gave me seaborn version as 0.10.0. When I am trying the use scatter plot , I am getting error as  "module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'scatterplot'" I tried searching over the internet, but was not able to get any clarity as it was saying some versioning issues. But I wanted to check what are the functions included as part of this module.

Below is the code:

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.scatterplot(x="A", y="B", data= abc)
```

Can anyone please help if there is any way to know the functions of a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seaborn documentation is a great place to start: [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html).

This should point you in the right direction and also give you the benefit of documenting parameters you need to pass in along with examples.

If you merely want to see a list of methods then you can use the Python `dir()` method and pass in `sns` as a parameter.  Your code would look like this:

`dir(sns)`

This will output to the console or terminal a list of attributes and methods.

Python docs for `dir` method [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: Awesome This is what I was looking for ..Thank You very much for your help